# React Router: strangely matched Route path props passed to its wrapper

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

According to [React Router Doc](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func), `you can spread routeProps to make them available to your rendered Component`, code below works as I expected: users will see `Test` if entering `/test`, and `404` for `/test2`.

If I remove `{...rest}`, I expected users will always see `Test` because the Route without a path should always match. But it still behaves the same. Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

```js
function RouteWrapper({ children, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest} 
      render={() => children}
    />
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <RouteWrapper path="/test">Test</RouteWrapper>
        <Route>404</Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

[CodesandBox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-bgsng?file=/example.js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting.

It appears to be because of how the `Switch` component [is implemented](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/Switch.js). The following snippet from the code is of particular interest:

```
let element, match;

React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, child => {
  if (match == null && React.isValidElement(child)) {
    element = child;

    const path = child.props.path || child.props.from;

    match = path
      ? matchPath(location.pathname, { ...child.props, path })
      : context.match;
  }
});
```

As you can see, the component simily looks through its children components and finds the `path` prop. It assumes you've passed a proper `path` prop to each `Route` component.

So it doesn't matter that you removed the `path` from your `Route`, because the Switch will take the `path` from your `RouteWrapper` component.